# MercadoLibre API: obtener productos - Offset no puede ser mayor a 4000

Tags: mercadolibre

Tengo una integración con MercadoLibre en donde hago esta query:

```
https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search?category=MLA105182&state=TUxBUENBUGw3M2E1&offset=5000
```

El problema viene solo cuando offset es > 4000.
Revisé la documentación y no hubo ningún cambio.
Quiero abrir un ticket a Mercadolibre pero me dice que tengo que ser un Developer Certificado...
¿Alguien con el mismo problema?

Comment: Ni idea de esa api pero.. es [esto](https://developers.mercadolibre.com.mx/en_us/en_us/items-and-searches)? Ahí dan una forma de correr búsquedas sobre más de 1000 elementos sin usar offset

Comment: @Alfabravo Lo estuve viendo y no. Al parecer solo funciona para el endpoint que pide los productos de un vendedor. Yo quiero ver todos los productos de una categoría. Añadí el parámetro "search_type=scan" a la query original y no devuelve el scroll_id, que es el valor que tiene que devolver y tengo que mandar en cada request para que me devuelva más de 4000.